# Converting SVG to EMF without loss of data

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have downloaded several `SVG` files and need to convert them to `EMF` format ( Enhanced Meta File ). I have used `Inkscape`'s *Save as* to save it as `.emf` but loss of data occurred ( I was warned by `Inkscape` too that this might occur when I was closing the document ).

Is there a way to convert `SVG` to `ENF` without loss of conversion?

*I am newbie, please take this into consideration when answering.*

Thank you for your time and help. Best regards.

Comment: You can not, in the general case. Only if you can limit yourself to a common subset then it is possible, if not then no. There's no automatic switch that can make them inter operate above this.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with EMFs in particular, but the general problem when converting between different vector formats is that certain objects (such as text, Bézier polygons with borders or gradients) are not available in the target format. Ideally, Inkscape converts its objects to objects which are supported by the target format. If you experience losses during conversions, this conversion failed for some reason or Inkscape does not convert the objects as they are supported by a higher version of the target format than the one you need.

Thus, if some objects are lost in format conversion, you can sometimes work around this by manually converting them (in Inkscape) to more primitive objects before format conversion. In most cases, *Object to Path* will do the job. What objects you need to convert exactly and to which extent, is however something you have to find out by experiment. Also, this can be quite tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Using LibreOffice draw as an intermediary seems to help.  Inkscape > SVG > LibreOffice export as EMF