# SVG exported to EMF loses precision, but exported as PNG looks fine

Tags: inkscape, png, file-format

I am Windows desktop programmer that needs to convert certain SVG into EMF in order to use it for programming.

My graphics design skills are at beginner level, but I have managed to convert SVG file into EMF successfully using Inkscape. However, the result is not looking as the original one, it is less "precise" so to say. If I export the SVG as PNG the result is the same as the original file. Unfortunately I need vector format that Windows recognizes and that is only EMF ( I am using pure WinAPI and C++, hence this limitation... ).

To see exactly what I mean, original SVG, and EMF and PNG that I made are [here](http://speedy.sh/FxUT2/test.rar). Just click on the *Download:test.rar* ( see the image below ).

[image]

The problem seems to be the dimensions of the EMF file ( it should be 90 x 120 ) as the picture is crystal clear when I resize my application to bigger dimensions.

I am asking your help to get the same graphic quality of the EMF file as the original SVG.

To further help you in your efforts to solve my problem, [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/km8Rr/EMF-app.rar) is a small application that will display EMF in a window. **Just keep the EMF in the same place the application is, and name the EMF as `test.emf`.**

Thank you for your time and efforts. Best regards.

Comment: emf  has a weird accuracy. yes indeed.  try scaling the art. Better ask on slashdot or superuser, i dont think any of the graphic designers i know have ever used emf in their life

Comment: @joojaa: OK, thank you for your advice. Should I then delete the question here?

Comment: No, i dont think so. You still might cet an answer. I just wanted to letypu know that thiscs not nesseserily the most productive venue for you

Comment: Side note, Wetransfer.com is a much better tool for sharing files in my experience, although the links are only live for 1 week. Dropbox is good for longer-term storage. I can't even download your files because it's an EXE file and I'm using a Mac - and even if I was on my PC, I wouldn't want some junk transferring program on it.

What program are you using that needs EMF?

Comment: @mrcharlie: you just have to click on *Download:test.rar* above the yellow stars, `.rar` file will automatically start downloading. Thank you for your suggestions. I am using `C++` and `pure Win32 API`.

Comment: Haha damn, I hate the file-sharing sites that do that.

Comment: @DumbNic: Worth a try, thank you. Best regards.

Comment: You might also try [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/35455/19174).

Answer (score 1):

EMF is something i have used a few times. From my own experience, it's not very accurate, and is an older format that doesn't support the precision level that you get with EPS or SVG.

Can you use an EPS file? What about WMF?

If not, try breaking the resulting image into smaller pieces. In other words, instead of one solid "big" shape, make it from smaller shapes "stacked" atop each other.

Comment: *Can you use an EPS file?* WinAPI supports only EMF as far as I know. MS Word can open EPS file so I will investigate if there is some way to use EPS in WinAPI. *What about WMF?* EMF is improved WMF format ( Microsoft fixed some bugs ). *If not, try breaking the resulting image into smaller pieces* It will be hard, but I will try and report my results. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: I also have **tried** to use WMF or EMF some years ago. From time to time I need to test it as an option but always, always fails to do a decent job.

Comment: One option to explore (that also fails) is to use a diferent scale, probably bigger scale and resize it... and another one is to have no curved paths, but a series of segmented curves.

Answer (score 0):

Corel draw has an excellent wmf and emf export engine which replicates the accuracy of the original. Curves stay as curves

Comment: The op mentioned SVG. Does Corel handle that? Please explain better what you mean! Welcome!